# Reading Froms.py code from Model data in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a some class in forms.py and I want reading code by user entry in specific model

for example This code need read from model user entry

```
class sample(forms):
    A = forms.textbox()
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but can't you simply use `User.objects...` query methods to get whatever data you need inside this `layout` function?

Comment: I have some model . I want code of forms.py read from models.py model content

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand much from your question. But as I understand, you want to create your form on the model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

or

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-modelform-create-form-from-models/

Comment: Dear im in developing platform to creat form based on created model by user in ui . Form generator for user in ui